# Download a pdf and upload it on s3 in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, amazon-s3, rest-client

So basically I'm trying to download a pdf file and upload it on an amazon bucket, is it possible to do it without creating a temp file ?

To download the pdf im doing this:

```
RestClient::Request.execute(
  :method => :get,
  :url => "#{@url}/test/#{id}/pdf",
  :headers => json_headers.merge(jwt_headers(access_token))
) do |response|
  disconnect if response.code == 401
  return unless response.code == 200
  response.body
end
```

But then can I upload the response.body to amazon directly as a pdf ?
Im kinda new to rails so if there is a better way or if this is just plain wrong, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

You can use s3 gem for same, S3 library provides access to Amazon’s Simple Storage Service. 
Check [here](https://github.com/qoobaa/s3).

Add s3 gem in your Gemfile and below code work for you.

```
require 'open-uri'
require 's3'

aws_object = S3::Service.new(access_key_id: 'YOUR_ACCESS_KEY', secret_access_key: 'YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY') # Save it on server for security.
bucket = aws_object.buckets.find('bucket_name')
url = 'http://www.example.com/url' # Your file url
downloded_file = open(url)

new_file = bucket.objects.build('desired_file_name_with_extention')
new_file.content = (File.read downloded_file)

new_file.save
```

Comment: I would like to keep using rest-client to download the file, ans when I try that method using rest client, i get: No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_size

Answer (score 0):

You can this if your file is downloaded properly then you can upload this at a time, for uploading to `s3` bucket you need to configure [`AWS S3`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html) bucket after that follow this below

In the `Gemfile`

```
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2'
```

Then bundle install

```
# Configuration
Aws.config.update({
    region: 'region_name', #=> like 'us-east-2'
    credentials: Aws::Credentials.new('S3_ACCESS_KEY', 'S3_SECRET_KEY')
})


#=> do |response|
File.open("#{response.headers['content-id']}_#{response.headers['object-id']}.pdf", 'wb') do |f|

    # Save pdf to application root folder
    f.write(response.body)
    s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region:'us-east-2')
    file_name =  "#{Rails.root}/#{response.headers['content-id']}_#{response.headers['object-id']}.pdf"
    bucket_name = 'S3_BUCKET_NAME'

    # Upload this file to s3 bucket
    key = File.basename(file_name)
    obj = s3.bucket(bucket_name).object(key)
    obj.upload_file(file_name, acl:'public-read')

    # Remove this file from application root folder at a time if you don't need this in the future
    #FileUtils.rm_f(file_name)
end
```

If you need to remove this file after uploading to `s3` then uncomment this like `FileUtils.rm_f(file_name)`